# How to fire an onclick event in an url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to redirect people using a url to a page on my website. The problem is that the page is a popup window created from TinyBox. So basically, I want the whole site to load up and then open the popup, but I need to do this with a url. Can someone help me? Here my code:

```
<ul class="floatset">
    <li onclick="pauseAllVideos(); TINY.box.show({iframe:'/flash',boxid:'frameless',width:800,height:600,fixed:false,maskid:'bluemask',maskopacity:40,closejs:function(){closeJS()}})" class="footer_image_text1"><a class="flash"></a>Flash</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like:

```
$('.floatset li:first-child').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  pauseAllVideos();
    //copied the below from your original question, not familiar with TinyBox
  TINY.box.show( {iframe:'/flash', boxid:'frameless', width:800,height:600, fixed:false,maskid:'bluemask', maskopacity:40,closejs:function(){closeJS()}})
 })
```

You can then set the `href` on the anchor without the user being navigated away when they click on it.